# HTML ul type disks come out as squares

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm really new to HTML and I have some problems with displaying lists. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Preceding Text</p>
    <ol type="I">
        <li>
            List Item 1
            <ol type="a">
                <li>Nested Item 1.1</li>
                <li>Nested Item 1.2</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            List Item 2
            <ol type ="1">
                <li>Nested Item 2.1</li>
                <li>Nested Item 2.2
                <ul typeof ="disc">
                    <li>Nested Item 2.2.1</li>
                    <li>Nested Item 2.2.2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Nested Item 2.2.3</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is with the "disc" part. Instead of discs chrome displays bullets as squares. Please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is wrong this line **`<ul typeof ="disc">`** to update this new **`<ul type ="disc">`**

#### check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RpjU4/)

HTML

Preceding Text

```
<ol type="I">
    <li>
        List Item 1
        <ol type="a">
            <li>Nested Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Nested Item 1.2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        List Item 2
        <ol type ="1">
            <li>Nested Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Nested Item 2.2
            <ul type ="disc">
                <li>Nested Item 2.2.1</li>
                <li>Nested Item 2.2.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Nested Item 2.2.3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. For some reason VS was giving me warning: "Unknown attribute 'type'." so I though it was wrong..

Answer (score 1):

use `list-style-type: disc` on the li element